# RegularExpressionValidator for user name

Tags: asp.net, validation, reg-expressionvalidator

I want to use ASP `RegularExpressionValidator` to check if the user entered a name which consists of `3-8` characters (English only).
What do I need to write in the `ValidationExpression`?
I tried this one  `^([\S\s]{0,4})$` but it doesnt seem to work...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to match letters of the alphabet 3-8 characters long try this...

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3,8}$
```

- `^` = start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]` = A-Z upper or lower case
- `{3,8}` = 3-8 occurences
- `$` = end of string

Comment: I think `RegularExpressionValidator` assumes you're matching the entire string, so try removing the `^` and `$`.